# bash script with optional input arguments using getopt

Tags: bash, arguments, getopts

I have copied code from [tutorialspoint's getopt article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/getopt.htm) and got the following script to work (**sort of**):

```bsh
##argument_script.sh
VARS=`getopt -o i::o:: --long input::,output:: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$VARS"

# extract options and their arguments into variables.
while true ; do
    case "$1" in

        -i|--input)
            case "$2" in
                "") MAPPE='/default/input/here/' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) MAPPE=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            esac ;;
        
            -o|--output)
            case "$2" in
                "") OUTPUTFOLDER='/default/input/here/' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) OUTPUTFOLDER=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
        esac ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
    esac
done

echo "${MAPPE}"
echo "${OUTPUTFOLDER}"

#do something here..
```

that is, I have two optional argument flags `-i`/`--input` and `-o`/`-output`.
I have a problem with the script currently:

To overwrite the default value of a flag, you need to write the value you want right after the flag, without any spaces.
example: if i wanted to pass `/c/` into `-i` and `/f/` into `-o`, i would need to call the script as: `bash argument_script.sh -i/c/ -o/f/`. Notice the missing spaces.
If I were to write `bash argument_script.sh -i /c/ -o /f/` the variables `MAPPE` and `OUTPUTFOLDER` would be using the default values. 
**Can the script be rewritten, so the arguments passed into `-i`/`-o` needs to be written after a space** (example: `bash argument_script.sh -i /c/ -o /f/`)

Comment: Do you have a `#!` line as the first line of your script?

Comment: That can't work. If you allow the next argument after `-i` to be its value, then there's no other way to pass `-i` without value than by making sure `-i` is the last argument. As  `cmd -i -o` would be `-i` with `-o` as the option's argument (like `--input=-o`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is because you have an extra `:` in your `getopt`. Just change your `getopt` line to this and it will work:

```
VARS=`getopt -o i:o: --long input:,output: -- "$@"`
```

However, this is a very, very convoluted way of writing your script. Here is a simpler version (also correcting some bad practices like capitalized variables):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

##argument_script.sh
vars=$(getopt -o i:o: --long input:,output: -- "$@")
eval set -- "$vars"

mappe='/default/input/here/'
outputFolder='/default/input/here/'

# extract options and their arguments into variables.
for opt; do
    case "$opt" in
      -i|--input)
        mappe=$2
        shift 2
        ;;
      -o|--output)
        outputFolder=$2
        shift 2
        ;;
    esac
done
echo "mappe: $mappe"
echo "out: $outputFolder"
```

You can now do:

```
$ ./argument_script.sh -i /c/  -o /f/
mappe: /c/
out: /f/
```

Note that it also works if you run `./argument_script.sh -i/c/  -o/f/`. The space is not required, it is allowed.

Comment: There's something I'd like to understand. The loop that processes the options is looping over the positional arguments. The first element is `$1`. After the first iteration, you might have shifted, so the next thing to process is still at `$1`. But the next iteration would be with `$2`. So I would think, you'd miss it. But that's not the case. Whats going on?

Comment: I think I get it. The `for` iterates over the original `"$@"`, that one is not updated.

Comment: @leo The point of the `shift` is to remove the _next_ parameter, the value, so we move to the next argument. Remember, we are processing something like `-i /c/  -o /f/` so when we see the `-i`, we want to jump to the `-o`, not keep processing the `/c/`. But for loops don't jump back to the beginning and repeat everything, that's the point of `for` loops: they iterate over all the elements one by one. They don't go back to the 1st element.

Comment: Right. I initially assumed that the for would operate with the updated array after the stripping of the elements with `shift`. That's not the case. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour, unfortunately, as implemented by the GNU `getopt(3)` function the `getopt(1)` utility is based on. From its manpage (emphasis mine):

> Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there  is  text  **in
> the current `argv`-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, `-oarg`)**, then it is returned in  `optarg`,  otherwise `optarg` is set to zero.

If you want to be able to use a space between the option and its argument (e.g. `-o value` instead of `-ovalue`) you have to make its argument *non-optional*, by using a single `:` after the option char in the spec.

Comment: The option is still optional. If you use the version in my answer, both options are optional. You can't pass the option with no argument but that is normal: this isn't an option that makes sense without an argument.